# Prove $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} J_i \subseteq \bigcap_{i=a}^{b} J_i$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathscr J=\{J_i : i \in \Bbb N\}$ be a family set and let $a,b$ be natural numbers with $a \le b$. Prove that:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} J_i \subseteq \bigcap_{i=a}^{b} J_i$$

Attempt: Let x $\in$ $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} J_i$. Then there exists a set $\{1,2,..a,a+1,...,b\}$.

Not really sure where to go with this proof. I am pretty lost.

Comment: Can you describe what this statement says at an informal level? How convinced are you that it is true?

Comment: Try looking at the definition of being in $\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}J_i$. If $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}J_i$, it belongs to **every** $J_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice first that $$|\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}J_i| \leq |\bigcap_{i=a}^{b}J_i|$$ If this is not true, there exists $x$ so that $$\forall i: x \in J_i \land \exists i \in [a,b]: x \notin J_i$$ which is a clear contradiction. How does this translate into LHS being a subset of RHS? Can you form an equivalent logical statement with assuming the converse

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}J_i \not\subset\bigcap_{i=a}^{b}J_i$$

Comment: Can you give me another hint?

Comment: Experiment with concrete examples. If $a=5$ and $b = \infty$ and $J_i = \{1,2\}$ when $i > 4$ and $J_i = \{1\}$ for $i < 5$, then $\{1\} \subset \{1,2\}$ which is true and supports this claim. Usually these kinds of proofs start with identifying $x$ as a member of the sets, and in this case, if $x$ is in LHS, $x$ is in RHS too. Converse, $x$ in LHS but not in RHS aims for contradiction. Intuitively converse would be " for all $i$, $x$ in $J_i$ but also for some $i$, $x$ not in $J_i$". Try to find and express this with logical symbols.